# Trying to save photos from camera into file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Trying to take a photo with a raspberry pi 3b plus camera. We are sending on a weather balloon into near space and need to take photos every 3 minutes and save all the photos. I don't know if we should save that to a file or some other source. Also, we need a photo every 3 minutes. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making a test image capture tagged with the date and time like this:

```
raspistill -dt -o /home/pi/image-%d.jpg
```

which should result in an image in `/home/pi` like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 pi pi    4397351 Nov 12 08:28 image-1112082809.jpg
```

Satisfy yourself regarding its quality and size. Then you can get an image taken every 3 minutes by adding an entry into your crontab like this:

```
*/3 * * * * raspistill -dt -o /home/pi/image-%d.jpg
```

---

In case you are unfamiliar with `cron`, you can edit your `crontab` using the command `crontab -e` and choosing the easiest editor which is `nano`. If you want to list and check your `cron` entries without editing them, use `crontab -l`

In case you are unfamiliar with `raspistill`, you can get help on its syntax and options with `raspistill --help`.

Just FYI, there's a veritable treasure trove of material about High Altitude Ballooning with Raspberry Pis on Dave Akerman's pages [here](https://www.daveakerman.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I don't have raspberry pi cam to test it on. This program uses opencv which captures the camera and then forever captures photos every 3min. Use ctrl + c to exit it.

```py
import time
import cv2
import os

# creates an image folder
if (not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/images")):
    os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + "/images")
counter = 0 # counter so each image name is different
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # gets the camera

while True:
    # Capture frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imwrite(os.getcwd() + "/images/" +
                    "image{}.jpg".format(counter), frame)
        counter += 1
    time.sleep(180)  # wait 3min
```